# How to Exclude DevTools in Spring Boot Native (GraalVM)

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Having a simple Spring Boot application ([generated](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=kotlin&platformVersion=3.0.0-RC1&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=native,devtools,web) on start.spring.io) with DevTools added as a dependency, if you try to build the native image:

```bash
./gradlew nativeCompile
```

You get an executable that if you try to run fails with:

```
./build/native/nativeCompile/demo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer] for factory type [org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$throwing$0(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:650)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FailureHandler.lambda$handleMessage$3(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:674)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:231)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:459)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:455)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:273)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:252)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt.main(DemoApplication.kt:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartScopeInitializer
        at java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1136)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:224)
        ... 9 more
```

There are some issues on GH regarding this, but none of them is addressing the exact issue, any fix or workaround. Does anyone know how to exclude DevTools during `nativeCompile`?

**Update**:
It seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32853) with Spring Boot and they're trying to solve it. (Will update it when the issue is resolved.)